# Law of Conservation of Energy and a moving bar magnet through a coil?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

How would you do this question?[image]

What I've currently attempted is applying the Law of Conservation of Energy formula where $E_i = E_f$, and I've accounted for gravitational potential energy and kinetic energy. I'm not sure what else to include.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! bump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint

If you have the kinetic and gravitational potential energy accounted for, it should be a simple matter of determining how much kinetic energy the magnet *should* have after falling 1m compared to how much kinetic energy it *actually* has after falling 1m (which is what the final velocity is stated for).

Comment: I get what you mean now, because that lost energy is the energy that has been transferred to electrical. But I'm not sure which formula to use to account for this loss in energy, or the kinetic energy it 'actually' has\

Comment: Oh sorry, they do give you actual kinetic energy. Nevermind

Comment: Can I have another hint to calculate what the 'theoretical kinetic energy' should be?

Comment: I have calculated that the theoretical $E_k$ should be $0.05 v^2$. How do I go about calculating v?

Comment: You will need to use the "classic" equations of motion, specifically $v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2ad$ where $a$ and $d$ refer to acceleration and displacement respectively.

Comment: I got D as the answer, but the answers are saying that it's B

Comment: Heh, not sure what to tell you then. A 100g mass on earth should have 0.98N of weight-force, to displace 1m with that force will take exactly 0.98J ($W = Fd$). Assuming the answer is B, if the coil was not there, the magnet should be falling with 4.422 J of energy (kinetic energy left + energy for answer) which translates to 9.4 m/s, which due to $v_f = v_i + at$ would take 0.95s of free-fall, implying due to $d = \frac{at^2}{2}$ a drop height of 4.5m or so - contrary to the premise!